# R arguments not being passed to pipe within custom function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, magrittr

I regularly have to perform a piped series of operations that groups by one or more (usually two) variables, finds the mean and confidence interval of one or more variables, and outputs the results to a summary table for plotting or reporting.

Usually I do this by copying and pasting a script e.g.:

```
aggdata <- data %>% group_by(Time, Category) %>%
    summarise(mean.Volume = mean(Volume, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.Volume = sd(Volume, na.rm = TRUE),
              n.Volume = n(),
              Volume = sum(Volume))%>%
    mutate(se.Volume = sd.Volume / sqrt(n.Volume),
           lower.ci.Volume = mean.Volume - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume,
           upper.ci.Volume = mean.Volume + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume)
```

So I tried writing a function for this, however for both of the following:

```
aggvols1 <- function(data, a, b, values) {
   data %>% group_by(a, b) %>%
    summarise(mean.Volume = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.Volume = sd(values, na.rm = TRUE),
              n.Volume = n(),
              Volume = sum(values))%>%
    mutate(se.Volume = sd.Volume / sqrt(n.Volume),
           lower.ci.Volume = mean.Volume - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume,
           upper.ci.Volume = mean.Volume + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume)
}
```

and

```
aggvols2 <- function(data, a, b, values) {
  groupvars <-c(data$a,data$b) #also does not work if just use c(a,b)
  data %>% group_by(groupvars) %>%
    summarise(mean.Volume = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.Volume = sd(values, na.rm = TRUE),
              n.Volume = n(),
              Volume = sum(values))%>%
    mutate(se.Volume = sd.Volume / sqrt(n.Volume),
           lower.ci.Volume = mean.Volume - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume,
           upper.ci.Volume = mean.Volume + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume)
}
```

followed by e.g.

```
test <- aggvols1(data=salesdata, a=Participation, b=Time_Period, values=volumes_sold)
```

returns the same error message:

```
Error in aggvols1(data=salesdata, a=Participation, b=Time_Period, values=volumes_sold) : 
  unused arguments (a = Participation, b = Time_Period)
```

How can I make the arguments a and b get passed as the grouping variables so that the function returns a table of grouped means and CIs?

Ultimately my goal is not just to get this running but alter it so that instead of specifying two grouping variable columns and a single value column, I can specify a vector of grouping variables and a vector of values variables so that it can group by and calculate responses for one or multiple columns, adding the column name of each input "values" variable as a suffix to each output column for differentiation.

Any advice on how to fix the function so it runs and/or how to improve the function as described above would be greatly appreciated; I'm new to writing my own functions but am trying to move towards using them instead of just copying and pasting code where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also would like to adivse you to use `rlang` syntax but do have a little different approach.
You have to use quotations to get dplyr to accept varnames the way you want to provide them inside a function.
The following code is working for me.
Also have a look at `vignette("programming", "dplyr")` and the RStudio Cheat Sheet for `rlang` here https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/.

```
aggvols1 <- function(data, a, b, values) {

  a <- enquo(a)
  b <- enquo(b)
  values <- enquo(values)

  data %>% group_by(!! a, !! b) %>%
    summarise(mean.Volume = mean(!! values, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.Volume = sd(!! values, na.rm = TRUE),
              n.Volume = n(),
              Volume = sum(!! values))%>%
    mutate(se.Volume = sd.Volume / sqrt(n.Volume),
           lower.ci.Volume = mean.Volume - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume,
           upper.ci.Volume = mean.Volume + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using curly-curly from `rlang` to pass unquoted variables in the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang) 


aggvols1 <- function(data, a, b, values) {
   data %>% 
      group_by({{a}}, {{b}}) %>%
      summarise(mean.Volume = mean({{values}}, na.rm = TRUE),
                sd.Volume = sd({{values}}, na.rm = TRUE),
                n.Volume = n(),
                Volume = sum({{values}}))%>%
      mutate(se.Volume = sd.Volume / sqrt(n.Volume),
             lower.ci.Volume = mean.Volume - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume,
             upper.ci.Volume = mean.Volume + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.Volume - 1) * se.Volume)
}
```

Assuming `qt` is another function defined, you can then call the function `aggvols` by

```
aggvols(data=salesdata, a=Participation, b=Time_Period, values=volumes_sold)
```

Comment: I tried this and now I'm getting another, different error:

test <- aggvols3(data=salesdata, a=Time_Period, b=Participation, values=volumes_sold)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Time_Period' not found. 

Which is odd because names(salesdata) results in:

 [1] "Week_ID"        "Province"        "Retailer"   "Fascia"          "Channel" "Outlet_ID"     
 [7] "Week_End_Date"   "Participation"       "Time_Period"     "volumes_sold"       "volumes_sold_other"

Comment: That is weird... Can you try with `aggvols(salesdata, Participation, Time_Period, volumes_sold)` ? Or maybe add a reproducible example?